# Is there a way of finding the length and width of a JPanel and/or JFrame in Java?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I need to know this for a science fair project.

Comment: getSize() will be a good place to start

Comment: @iluxa if that were an answer i'd upvote that too. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Since both [JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) and [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) extend [java.awt.Component](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html), they both implement the [getSize()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getSize%28%29) method, which returns a [Dimension](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html), which has integer properties for "width" and "height".

Answer (score 2):

`JPanel.getSize()` or `JFrame.getSize()`.